# how to have multiple type for generics in child class

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, inheritance, generic-programming

I have a BaseController

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : ApiController 
{

    protected APIResponseTO<T> _reponse;

    protected IHttpActionResult CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatus, T data)
    {
        _reponse = new APIResponseTO<T>()
        {
            HttpStatus = httpStatus,
            Data = data
        };
        return Ok(_reponse);
    }
}
```

Now I want that any Class which inherits this class can define multiple types for T as

```
 public class CustomerController : BaseController<T>
 {

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {

        var customers = _customerService.GetCustomers();
        //call Parent Class CreateResponse() to create IHttpActionResult object
        //here customers is IEnumerable<Customer>
        return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, customers)
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        var custId= _customerService.AddCustomers();
        //call Parent Class CreateResponse() to create IHttpActionResult object
        //here customer is integer(Single Object)
        return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, custId)
    }
}
```

What my requirement is either I can define somehow at the class level

```
public class CustomerController : BaseController<T> where T : Customer, IEnumerable<Customer>, int
 {
 }
```

or at Method Level

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post<T>([FromBody]Customer customer)
  where T : int
    {
        var custId= _customerService.AddCustomers();
        //call Parent Class CreateResponse() to create IHttpActionResult object
        //here customer is integer(Single Object)
        return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, custId)
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement here. You are constraining `T` to be 3 mutually exclusive types.

Comment: I don't understand either... What do you need here?

Comment: @DavidG, Defining generic Constraints in Child class

Comment: Constraints of what though, what do you want to be the `int` for example?

Comment: @Haytam,I want to define generic constraints in child class let the child class control the genric defintion

Comment: @DavidG, Get() will have Collection of Customer, Post() will have CustomerId(int), Delete() will have bool as data `T could be any object`

Comment: I think what he is saying is that he wants to be able to use multiple types in a  single instance.  I may be wrong but his question is not really clear.  You can allow multiple constraints on your generic class, but each instance can only take a single type.

Comment: Then make the base class have all those types as generic too.

Comment: You can achieve what you are looking for with a single type.  If you pass Customer, have get return IEnumberable<T> (Which is now customer) Assuming that all your id's are int, just return int for the id method

Comment: @bhmahler, you got my requirement in the right direction, but control generic definition of method level or have multiple type in instance class

Comment: By the way, part of your problem here is that you are trying to mould a WebAPI controller into something else. Keep your business logic completely distinct, preferably in a different project completely.

Comment: @DavidG, where you're finding business logic in my controller

Comment: What is *defining that generic at the class (instance) level* supposed to achieve?

Comment: Can I know why you keep the `_response` stored?

Comment: Does *I want to define generic constraints in child class let the child class control the generic definition* mean you want the child to control what the base can do? Cos that's not going to work. A base class does not know what it's instantiation does/is. an instanciation knows it's base but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understood exactly what you need, but I think I have an idea.
I think you should not use a generic class but instead use a generic method:

```
public class CustomerController : BaseController
{

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {

        var customers = new List<object>();
        return CreateResponse<List<object>>(HttpStatusCode.Created, customers);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        int custId = 17;
        return CreateResponse<int>(HttpStatusCode.Created, custId);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseController : ApiController
{

    protected IHttpActionResult CreateResponse<TData>(HttpStatusCode httpStatus, TData data)
    {
        // Problem here is that BaseController is not a generic class anymore, so you can't store your responses but then again, why would you want to store them in a variable?
        var reponse = new APIResponseTO<TData>()
        {
            HttpStatus = httpStatus,
            Data = data
        };

        return Ok(reponse);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your class like this (adding `<T>` after the class too)

```
public class CustomerController<T> : BaseController<T> where T : Customer, IEnumerable<Customer>, int {
}
```

will put the generic at the higher level